# Symbolic link with backup and delete

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a symbolic link that should backup the file (if it already exists) with a date suffix and delete the original file. I'm convinced that I missing something...

I'm doing this

`ln -v -b -f -s the_link original_file -t my_dir -S "20191101"`

In man page:

`-b`: backup if file already exists
`-f`: force remove if file exists
`-s`: symbolic (soft link)
`-t`: the destination dir
`-S`: the suffix that replaces backup normal suffix
`-v`: verbose

The ln creates first the correct link `the_link -> original_file` but, after that, I think it's creating another link `original_file -> original_file`. At least the verbose gives me this:

`/home/engdev/PFE/appl/lib/libCsReport.so -> '/home/engdev/PFE/#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/appl_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib/libCsReport.so'
/home/engdev/PFE/appl/lib/libCsReport.so -> libCsReport.so`

And, of course, the link is broken.

Thank's in advance for any help.

Here's my code:

```
for file in `ls plat_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib | awk -F "/" "{print $NF}"`
do
echo "creating backup: file: $HOME/PFE/plat/lib/$file"
echo "linking new lib: file: plat_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib/$file"
ln -v -b -f -s $PWD/plat_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib/$file $file -t $HOME/PFE/plat/lib/ -S "20191101"
done

for file in `ls appl_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib | awk -F "/" "{print $NF}"`
do
echo "creating backup: file: $HOME/PFE/appl/lib/$file"
echo "linking new lib: file: appl_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib/$file"
ln -v -b -f -s $PWD/appl_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib/$file $file -t $HOME/PFE/appl/lib/ -S "20191101"
done
```

Comment: `#` is the shell's comment character, everything starting with `#5799` on the line is ignored, since you didn't put the filename in quotes.

Comment: You have two `target` arguments in the script. Is that intentional?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: `-t` doesn't do what you think. `ln2(){ [ -e "$2" ] && mv -n "$2" "$3/$2$4" && ln -s "$1" "$2"; }; ln2 link target backupdir suffix`

Comment: @Barmar it's only one target, the -t is the directory that the link will be created. The quotes are OK, maybe I forgot to paste here in the code window, because the link is created two times.

Comment: You have two targets. `$PWD/appl_#5799_-_2019-195_19002034_-_Desativação_ASP/lib/$file` and `$file`

Comment: @jhnc You are right, removing the -t and entering the folder before creating the link, the command work's properly. Maybe there are a bug in -t? Thank you guys for your time.